# How to count frequency of word in c

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

Assume we have an array :

> you are alien and they are human

So, how to count the kind of string?

Output :

`you = 1 word`

Comment: Did you come up with any idea/algorithm yet?

Comment: i think to do it with `strcmp()` but there's confusing between same word and different word, any suggestion?

Comment: have you tried yet?then please show your code.

Comment: Do have a look at Ternary trees. http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/strings/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have done the tokenizing correctly, you can store each word into a vector of char* and use `strcmp` to compare your token (which is a char*) with each word in the vector.

Ex.)

```
 token_vector.push_back(token);
 for(auto i = 0; i < token_vector.size(); i++){
    if(strcmp(token, token_vector[i]) == 0) count++;
    else token_vector.push_back(token);
 }
```

Comment: This is C++ with STL libraries which aren't available in c.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some ideas to start with:

1. Store strings in **[array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure)** along with count (use strcmp). Add new string with `count = 1`, and increment count by 1 if string is already present. (linear search)
2. Store strings in **[hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)** (collision resolved by making linked list) and increment the count when same string is encountered.
3. Keep a **[trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)** and increment the count as leaf node
4. Store the strings in a **[BST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)** (**[RB tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)** for example) and increment the count if string is already present.

Follow the links to get the time/space complexity and implementation detail to make a sound decision about which data structure is best suited for your requirement. I'm'afraid adding pros and cons of each may make this post very wide.